# Как сделать "прилипание" двух полигонов

Tags: c#

В общем хочу соединить две линии между собой. Как сделать чтобы когда я конец второй линии приближал к первой чтобы он "прилипал" к нему. Как в любых cad-системах

Answer (score 3):

Подсчитать разницу между концом линии и опорной точкой, и если меньше "прилипающего" расстояния, присваивать концу линии значение опорной точки?